# How to mount local folder as network location (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, windows-networking

Under Windows 7, I'm trying to find a way to mount a local folder (e.g. C:\test_directory) as a top-level Windows network location (e.g. \\test_directory).

The folder doesn't even have to be actually shared, just as long as it locally appears at a definable \\location.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the share as (notice the absense of the backslash):

```
\test_directory
```

Although if you are on another computer / node on the network, you must firstly specify the computer / node name. E.g.:

```
\\HOMEPC\test_directory
```